# Runtime Error in Google Kick start using python

Tags: runtime-error, python-re

I am practicing 'Round D 2020 - Kick Start 2020' though I have properly done coding for Record Breaker problem and also showing correct answers for sample test cases still I am getting RE (Runtime error).
See attached screenshot and code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWdoL.png)

- 

```
T=int(input())
rlst=[]
if "\n" in T:
    T
for i in range(T):
    N=int(input())
    V=input()
    V_lst=V.split()
    rbday=0
    high_day=V_lst[0]
    if V_lst[0] > V_lst[1]:
        rbday=rbday+1
        high_day=V_lst[0]
    for n in range(1,N-1):
        if ((V_lst[n] > V_lst[n-1]) and (V_lst[n] > V_lst[n+1]) and (V_lst[n] > high_day)) :
            high_day=V_lst[n]
            rbday=rbday+1
    rlst.append(rbday)
    
for i in range(T):     
    print("Case {}# {}".format(i+1,rlst[i]))
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line: `if V_lst[0] > V_lst[1]:`, because you didn't consider the case where N is equal to 1, so this `V_lst[1]` is out of index.

I can share my solution, using Python 3.7 too:

```
T = int(input())

for case in range(1, T+1):
    N = int(input())
    V = list(map(int, input().split()))
    n_breaks = 0
    d = 0     #It's like previous high day in your code.
    for i in range(N):
        if N == 1:
            n_breaks = 1
            break
        if i != N-1:
            if V[i] > d and V[i] > V[i+1]:
                n_breaks += 1
                d = V[i]
        else:
            if V[i] > d and V[i] > V[i-1]:
                n_breaks += 1
    print(f"Case #{case}: {n_breaks}")
```